# Install 32 bit OCX Files / Add-Ins on Access 2016 64 bit

Tags: ms-access, ocx

From now on we are running OCX-Files and some Add-Ins in 32 bit MS Access, planned would have been a changeover on 64 bit, i already tested different ways of register the ocx in the syswow64 folder and so on, but it seems Ms Access is not recognising the 32 bit control elements.
Is there a way to run them on the 64 bit MS Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. For 64-bit Office you need 64-bit controls / COM Add-ins.

See [Choose between the 64-bit or 32-bit version of Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-between-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#32or64Bit=2016) :

> ### Reasons to choose the 32-bit version
>
> **You have 32-bit COM Add-ins with no 64-bit alternative.** You can continue to run 32-bit COM add-ins in 32-bit Office on 64-bit Windows. You can also try contacting the COM Add-in vendor and requesting a 64-bit version.
>
> **You use 32-bit controls with no 64-bit alternative.** You can continue to run 32-bit controls in 32-bit Office like Microsoft Windows Common Controls (Mscomctl.ocx, comctl.ocx), or any existing 3rd-party 32-bit controls.